# Creating array from a dataframe taking one column value as a reference

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, dataframe

I am dealing with this issue since some days ago, but I couldn´t find an answer. Hope you can help me.

This is my dataframe:

```
   Date              Attribute       Quantity
0 2017-12-14           large          -39
0 2017-12-15           large          -80
1 2017-12-15           large          -30
2 2017-12-14           short          -15
2 2017-12-15           short          -100
4 2017-12-15           short          -10
1 2017-12-15           short           20
3 2017-12-15           short           60
3 2017-12-15            big            80
5 2017-12-15            big           104
```

What I want to do? I would like to calculate [XIRR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179099/user-defined-xirr-function-exception-handling) for each `Attribute` ítem. For this I require `Date` and `Quantity` (as an array), but based on each `Attribute` item listed in the second column. For example, given `large`, I would like to extract `Dates` and `quantities` (as an array) for `large`.

Given that, I think my best choice is to create specific arrays based on the `Attibute` column and then execute the aforementioned function (please, let me know if you consider another approach to this problem). So, I generated one array `df1= df[['Date','Quantity']].as_matrix()` which produce

```
[[Timestamp('2017-12-14 00:00:00') -39]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') -80]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') -30]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-14 00:00:00') -15]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') -100]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') -10]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') -20]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') 60]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') -80]
 [Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00') 104]]
```

As you can see this array includes **all** the attributes, but I would like to get something like `For / each` function according to each attibute in column `Attribute`. How can I do this? **Is this the best approach/alternative to my final goal?**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

PD: I should mention that the function I would like to use works over attribute as a group (because it requieres dates and quantity, all together). It works like `gruopby`.

Thanks

Comment: You can apply functions to rows as Series.  `df.apply(some_function, axis=1)`

Comment: Nah, I don't think this is a good idea. I disagree with the posted answer, and `apply` is the last solution you should look at. Please tell me what it is you want to do. You most likely need a groupby + something (I don't know what, because you didn't tell me what you want to do... now you know why explaining your problem is important).

Answer (score 1):

Consider applying a function to each row of the DataFrame:

```
def row_func(row):
    if row['Atribute'] == 'large':
        return row['quantity']
    etc...

df['new_column'] = df.apply(row_func, axis=1)
```